# How to indicate expand/collapse points when writing code in Visual C# Express 2008?

Tags: c#

When coding in Visual C# Express 2008, you can expand/collapse code segments using the +/- symbols on the left hand corner of the text-editor. These appear automatically when a function is created.

Is their anyway I can manually add an expand/collapse point to a code segment?

Comment: Not worth an answer, but it *is* possible to create arbitrary code folds exactly like the automatic ones. ViEmu is one plugin that does this to mimic Vim's text folding behaviour, but if you don't use Vim, you won't want ViEmu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define a region manually

```
#region myRegion
// your collapsible code here
#endregion
```

Comment: I slightly changed the code to have "endregion" instead of "end region"

Comment: thanks,

the keyboard shortcut after highlighting the code is 
ctrl+K, ctrl+S, #re and then hit enter

after that change the name

cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the fix, Eilon!  If it wasn't for good IDE editors, my code would never compile...  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#region Any region name goes here

... code goes here ...

#endregion
```

Note that the #endregion has no space in it.